# Can't access website from outside?

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

So I can't access my website from outside for some reason. I've tried the command "ping xxx" from cmd but I get a timeout. I can access the database from outside though. I have port-forwarded 80 and also tried turning off my firewall & allowing port 80 TCP/UDP both in and out.

I can access it locally (from my computer and on the same network)

My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<Directory "D:/wamp/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from none
</Directory>
```

Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this Apache 2.2 syntax with Apache 2.4 syntax.

From

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from none
```

To

```
Require all granted
```